# Error: winehq-devel depends wine-devel (=4.5~bionic), Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: 18.04, wine

When i write in the terminal sudo apt install --instal-recommends winehq-devel, this error appears (error in title).
How can i resolve it?
My Ubuntu version is 18.04.2.

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party repository?

Comment: winehq-devel does not seem to be in the standard repos

Comment: I have (apparently) the same problem. Used the wine-devel/ubuntu repository from winehq; had issues with it and held/broken packages. I'm using Mint 19, so I plan to ask similar question on linux stack and reference this one.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem of endless dependencies installing winehq-* on my Ubuntu 18.04.2 (upgraded from ubuntu 16.04). After lots of googling and trying out what worked for me at the end was to build wine locally, which was way faster than I thought.

So here how I done it: (Token from [winehq official wiki](https://wiki.winehq.org/Building_Wine))

1. clone:

   ```
   git clone git://source.winehq.org/git/wine.git ~/wine-dirs/wine-source
   ```
2. build 64-bit version:

   ```
   cd ~/wine-dirs/wine-build/
   ../wine-source/configure --enable-win64
   make
   DO NOT INSTALL (32-bit version should be installed first)
   ```
3. build 32-bit verions:

   ```
   cd ~/wine-dirs/wine32-build/
   PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/pkgconfig ../wine-source/configure --with-wine64=../wine64-build
   make

   PKG_CONFIG_PATH should point to the location of the 32 bit pkgconfig files, probably /usr/lib or /usr/lib32.
   ```

**DEPENDECIES**:

**libfaudio**

1. depends on SDL2-2.0.9 (follow [instruction](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/multimedia/sdl2.html))
2. clone https://github.com/FNA-XNA/FAudio
3. build

   ```
   cd build_faudio/ 
   cmake ../FAudio-master/
   make -j 4
   ```

**i386 version of some libs**

1. sudo apt-get install libx11-dev libx11-dev:i386 [from](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189430/wine-x-development-files-not-found)
2. sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev:i386 libfreetype6-dev [from](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114460/how-to-install-lfreetype-using-wine)